# AD Computers Show users Without Login

Tags: active-directory

For some strange reason, random computers and random users, appear ad users folders without even login at computers. This appens at random dates.

Please any one have idea? I have none script running for that.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "appear"?

Comment: Hello @David, Can you please ellobarate your issue what strange you are seeing in AAD. It would be very helpful for us to provide asnswer if you provide pictures and with example.

Answer (score 0):

•   Please check thoroughly whether any unauthorized application is running in the background or not, and if it is running, then kindly uninstall it as it may be an attempt to sneak into your domain environment and steal viable and important information. Also, as you are saying that random computers and random users AD shared folders are popping at the login screen without authenticating in the client system, it might be possible that your Domain Controller account has been compromised by a remote hacker and your organization’s data is at severe risk of misuse and leak.

•   Also, check whether any inbound and outbound ports are continuously sending and receiving data through activity log in firewall and what type of communication is happening over those ports. Do an analysis of health status of your environment’s inbound and outbound gateway appliances for any breach or compromise of security policies and set of allowed defined rules. Ensure that your DC and any high privilege account credentials are not compromised and change all the passwords regarding them immediately.

•   Scan all the systems thoroughly with licensed and updated Anti-virus software and check for any data leakages.